Why PDO::FETCH_CLASS is working with small results and does not work with large results?
I'm trying to convert my SQL result into a class using PDO::FETCH_CLASS.
The code was working fine, until I encountered a query that generates 83 rows. The query returns two columns, one of type int and one of type text.
This is the error message:
 Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: App\Models\BibliaLectio::add():
 Argument #1 ($bibliaTextus) must be of type App\Models\BibliaTextus,
 array given,  called in
 /MYROUTE/src/App/Domain/Infrastructure/Mapper/Biblia/PdoBibliaMapper.php on line 60  
 and defined in /MYROUTE/src/App/Models/BibliaLectio.php:10

The code I'm using is as follows:
PdoBibliaMapper
//..

$bibliaLectio= new \App\Models\BibliaLectio();
$stmt=$this->pdo->run($sql,$params);
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, '\App\Models\BibliaTextus');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    $bibliaLectio->add($row); #Line 60
}

BibliaTextus
namespace App\Models;

class BibliaTextus
{

    private int $v;
    private string $t;

    public function toHtml()
    {
        return sprintf('<span class="versiculo">%s</span> %s',$this->v,$this->t);
    }
}

BibliaLectio
namespace App\Models;

class BibliaLectio
{

    private array $list;

    public function add(BibliaTextus $bibliaTextus) #Line 10
    {
        $this->list[]=$bibliaTextus;
    }

    public function toHtml()
    {
        $s='<h1>Texto Bíblico</h1><div class="textus-title"><p>';
        foreach ($this->list as $t)
        {
            $s.=$t->toHtml();
        }
        $s.='</p></div>';
        $s.='<p class="bibliaTextus"><a href="https://example.com/biblia" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Some Text</p>';
        return $s;
    }
}

Why does the code fail with a result of 83 rows and with smaller results it works fine and how could I solve this problem?

I suspect there's something weird about that row. Try doing var_dump($row); to see when it changes from an object to an array.

Use $row = $stmt->fetchObject(\App\Models\BibliaTextus::class) instead. If you have a autoloader simplify to $row = $stmt->fetchObject(BibliaTextus::class).

Conversion / Construction may fail because of some null values?

@Barmar the var_dump shows the first row, and then fails. Is not the content of the row, I have tested with different queries and the error persists.

@A.Cedano: "shows the first row, and then fails" - So the error occurs when trying to add the first result to $bibliaLectio?  What specifically was the output of that var_dump?

@MarkusZeller wowww that worked!  $row = $stmt->fetchObject(\App\Models\BibliaTextus::class) Thanks. But, is this still necessary$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, '\App\Models\BibliaTextus');?

I never used setFetchMode, because I like to call explicitly what I want to receive. But if you call fetchObject, you can remove that line.

I can't think of any reason why this would depend on the number of rows returned. It should either always return arrays or always return objects.

@David the ouput was one array with the columns of the query: array(2) { ["v"]=> int(1) ["t"]=> string(93) "Here the text... of first row" }

I just saw what my mistake was. The $stmt was created differently depending on some conditions and the setFetchMode I put it in the else part instead of putting it outside the block: if (...) { $stmt="..."; } else { $stmt="..."; #Here was the setFetchMode } It seems that using $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'MyClass::class') prevents these types of errors too.

I generally set the default fetch mode for the connection as a whole, rather than individual statements. I do it when I open the connection.

@Barmar in this case I don't need PDO::FETCH_CLASS for all results for this reason I don't set the fetch mode in the connection.

You can always override the default for specific fetches, with $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_xxx)
